# NAS setup and security

Tags: security, sftp, network-attached-storage

We wish to set up storage for the types of files:

A. Staff files (accessible from office only)
B. Management files (accessible from office only)
C. Graphics files (accessible outside of office via SFTP)

Questions:

1. We assume using one single NAS device for all of the above is a bad idea in terms of security, are we correct?
2. Our idea was to use NAS drive #1 for A and B (with folder permissions) and to use NAS drive #2 for C
3. Plus, using two firewall routers, one for NAS #1 and one for NAS #2... based on the assumption that this will completely isolate C from A and B in terms of security
4. How important is SFTP versus FTP? SFTP does not seem to be a common option as it's missing from Buffalo DriveStation and TeraStation.
5. How important is it that we set up VPN on the firewall routers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We assume using one single NAS device for all of the above is a bad idea in terms of security, are we correct?

Physical separation might be slightly easier to guarantee security but quite often logical separation can be already sufficient to achieve your security objectives.

> How important is SFTP versus FTP? SFTP does not seem to be a common option as it's missing from Buffalo DriveStation and TeraStation.

With FTP the credentials of your customers and your own users are transmitted in clear text and can relatively easily be intercepted. (And all up- and downloads as well)
That may or may not be an issue for you and your customers.

You can route FTP over a VPN to prevent such eavesdropping or change to a protocol such as SFTP which has encryption built in.

> How important is it that we set up VPN on the firewall routers?

That depends on your needs.